# Android appcompat-v7 libraries not recognized

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-appcompat

I moved my project to a new computer, with freshly installed Java and Android Studio, and it started acting weirdly. First, I was required to change "compile" with "implementation" in my gradle file. I did that, and then I was required to change my target sdk version, I did that too, and I also changed the version of the appcompat libraries, but in my classes the imports of appcompat are not recognized and also the methods, and the project does not build.

I cleaned, rebuilt, removed the .idea folder, did basically everything I could think of.

My gradle file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
   compileSdkVersion 26
   buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
   defaultConfig {
     applicationId "com.betako.pretprodazba"
     minSdkVersion 15
     targetSdkVersion 26
     versionCode 1
     versionName "1.0"
     multiDexEnabled true
   }
 packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
 }
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
  implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.1'
  implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:26.0.1'
  implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
  implementation files('libs/commons-net-1.4.1.jar')
}
```

Comment: What does it mean 'the project does not build'? What error are you getting?

Comment: Delete build folder manually and try rebuild project again